# What does kernel of an operating system do?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science

What exactly is a kernel of an operating system? What does it do? I tweaked my linux kernel a couple of times but didn't know why did I do it or what did it change.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The kernel is the central part of the operating system. It handles the 'behind the scenes' tasks so that your user space application (end user application) may run without knowing the inner details and complexities of the hardware.

Most importantly, a kernel performs:

1. Memory Management
2. Process Management
3. Virtual Filesystem support
4. Interrupt handlers

   + more.

You can read more about the inner working of Linux kernel in the wonderful book "Linux Kernel Development" by Robert Love.

Answer (score -1):

The kernel is the software that handles exceptions and interrupts in the system.